# A Webpack4 cssloader for all types of css code

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I added a cssloader to my webpack configuration file so that I could import my css files in my es6 code using webpack.

In one of my files I added

```
import '../css/Fonts.css'
```

And it worked with no problems.

I then tried to import the rest of my css, but couldn't. It seems the loader is only able to load some css. Not all of it.

This is the error that I received

```
ERROR in ./css/main.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./css/main.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError

(26:2) Unknown word

  24 |  background-position: center top;
  25 |  background-size: cover;
> 26 |  scale(1.2);
     |  ^
  27 |  flex-grow: 2;
  28 |  bottom: 0;

 @ ./css/main.css 2:14-79
 @ ./es6/Pages.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./images/myPhoto.jpg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./css/Components/Header.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./css/Components/Header.css) 4:38-69
 @ ./css/Components/Header.css
 @ ./es6/Pages.js
 @ ./src/index.js
```

I continued to remove css lines that cause error, to see what the next one which wouldn't work is.

scale(1.2)

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackTemplate = require('html-webpack-template');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  mode: 'development',     // set mode option, 'development' or 'production'
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    contact:'./src/contact.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: './index.html'
    }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './contact.html',
    inject: true,
    chunks: ['contact'],
    filename: './contact.html'
})
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

I would like a css loader that can load all css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with images. My css referenced images, but I didn't have an image loader.

After installing `file-loader` and `image-webpack-loader` with

```
npm install image-webpack-loader --save
npm install file-loader --save
```

I added one by adding this rule to my webpack config

```
  {
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
    use: [
      'file-loader',
      {
        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
        options: {
          bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
          disable: true, // webpack@2.x and newer
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

This is my full webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackTemplate = require('html-webpack-template');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  mode: 'development',     // set mode option, 'development' or 'production'
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    publications: './src/publications.js',
    advertise:'./src/advertise.js',
    contact:'./src/contact.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
              disable: true, // webpack@2.x and newer
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: './index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './advertise.html',
        inject: true,
        chunks: ['advertise'],
        filename: './advertise.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './publications.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['publications'],
      filename: './publications.html'
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './contact.html',
    inject: true,
    chunks: ['contact'],
    filename: './contact.html'
})
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```